# Can I test an Android Auto application in the car

Tags: android, android-auto

Is there a way to test an Android Auto application in the car, before submitting it to Google?

I have the application working in the DHU supplied by Google, but would like to confirm that it works properly in the car, prior to submission.

Comment: I was told by someone who had submitted an Android Auto application previously, that testing was not possible on the car until after the application had gone through review by Google.  I was wondering if with the new DHU set up testing  in a car prior to Google review was possible.

Comment: I'm having the same issue...I tested with DHU but when in the car nothing.  I  figure I have to submit for android auto review before it can be tested in vehicle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the UX/Safety concerns, you HAVE to be live on the Play Store - aka go through review (which is a new thing for Android) before testing in-car. However, this doesn't mean that you have to be public - you can publish to the Alpha or Beta channel, so only you and an optional controlled list of people can access it.